# Angular - Clear File Input

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that allows a user to fill out some fields as well as choose a profile picture. After submitting the form, I am trying to clear it so they could add another entry.

**Component HTML:**

```
<input type="file" #userPhoto name="userPhoto" id="userPhoto" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
```

**Component TS:**

```
@ViewChild('userPhoto') userPhoto: any;

...

private prepareSave(value): any {
 const Image = this.userPhoto.nativeElement;
 if (Image.files && Image.files[0]) {
   this.userPhoto = Image.files[0];
 }
 const ImageFile: File = this.userPhoto;
 const formData: FormData = new FormData();
 formData.append('ParentUserID', value.parentUserID);
 formData.append('FirstName', value.firstName);
 formData.append('LastName', value.lastName);
 formData.append('Age', value.age);
 formData.append('Photo', ImageFile, ImageFile.name);
 return formData;
}

...

<Submit Form>
clearSelectedPhoto() {
  this.userPhoto.nativeElement.value = null;
}
```

Now, I think the issue is that my `viewChild` is using `any` instead of `ElementRef`. However, when I change this, typescript complains about my line in the `prepareSave` method:

```
const ImageFile: File = this.userPhoto;
```

[ts]
Type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to type 'File'.
  Property 'lastModified' is missing in type 'ElementRef'.

How can I use `ElementRef` for my `viewChild` as well as assigning the photo to `File` later on?

I tried to cast it in my reset method but doesn't look like thats working either.

```
   clearSelectedPhoto() {
     (<ElementRef>this.userPhoto).nativeElement.value = null;
    }
```

Throws: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 9):

You have to get file from change event.

**Component HTML:**

```
<input #userPhoto type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)"/>
```

**Component TS:**

```
@ViewChild('userPhoto') userPhoto: ElementRef;
private _file: File;

private prepareSave(value): FormData {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('ParentUserID', value.parentUserID);
    formData.append('FirstName', value.firstName);
    formData.append('LastName', value.lastName);
    formData.append('Age', value.age);
    formData.append('Photo', this.file, this.file.name);
    return formData;
}


fileChange(event) {
    this.file = event.srcElement.files[0];
}
clearSelectedPhoto() {
    this.userPhoto.nativeElement.value = null;
}
```

When you use TS be shure to declare types everywhere you can, it avoids alot of misstakes. Don't return `any` from functions. Even if your function returns several types point on it in your function declaration ex: `getFile(): File | string`.

Don't use the same variable like this:

```
@ViewChild('userPhoto') userPhoto: any;
...
    if (Image.files && Image.files[0]) {
       this.userPhoto = Image.files[0];
    }
```

In your code you overwrote pointer to input element with file, and then when you tried to clear it's value `this.userPhoto.nativeElement.value = null;` you actualy wrote to `Image.files[0].value = null;`.

Answer (score -1):

you need to get the element using @ViewChild then make the element empty to remove the file

```
 #component.html
<input type="file" #userPhoto name="userPhoto" id="userPhoto" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />


 #component.ts{
  @ViewChild('userPhoto')
  myInputVariable: ElementRef;

  onFileChange(event){

   // when you done with process - clear the file
   this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
  
  }


}
```

Comment: Doesnt work. The input file is still remembering the previous file.